Inconsistency with Go-on 工, Ku not Kuu/Kou
Why is it that the Go-on reading of 工 isn't Kuu or Kou?
When a word with an -ng ending, it always results in a final u when behind a a o/u due to the ng ending producing a nasal u and then the nasal disappearing.
So, why isn't 工 in Go-on pronounced as Kuu/Kou?
I'm sure this has an easy answer somewhere but I just can't find it anywhere at all.
Thanks

Kanji‘s like 貢 共 公 供 宮 also have a short vowel in their Go-on, whereas 空 功 have a long vowel in Go-on. All of them end with -ng though. (I assume by ending in -ng you're referring to their original pronunciation in Chinese)

I'm not an expert, but based on the table of finals at Wikipedia's article "Sino-Japanese vocabulary", it looks like that is not the only case of a short -u or -o from a syllable that originally ended in -ŋ. You can also see other examples mentioned in dvx2718's comment. I guess you can conclude that it was either possible for long vowels to be shortened, or to not arise in the first place in this context. In fact, if we exclude cases of -yū which developed later on from the original diphthong -iu, I don't see any rime in the tables on that page that consistently yielded long -ū as opposed to short -u in Go-on (and actually, long -ū also doesn't seem to have been a common outcome in Kan-on).
Per Baxter's transcription system, the Middle Chinese pronunciation of 工 is reconstructed as *kuwng which per that table ought to yield a Go-on reading of ku or kū, and a Kan-on reading of kō (from kou). So the readings don't seem to be out of the ordinary.

Hmm, this is strange. The ng should have pronounced an extra u like it usually does with many other words that end with an ng. Something like Kuu, perhaps with many other words the long u shortened over time. I'm still unsure on why this is. Thank you for the comment.
